# Is a review request for a single class on topic for CR?

Tags: discussion, scope

Before I post another one of those. Is it ok, to post just a single utility class for review here like I did in [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86238/directly-initialize-variable-from-stdistream) or was I just lucky and I should post such questions on SO?

Comment: Our site scope is outlined in the [help/on-topic]. What makes you concerned that it would not be OK?

Comment: @200_success: Thank for the quick reply. I can't really put my finger on it, just a vague feeling, that questions on CR should have more code in it.

Comment: Go ahead and just post your question, then.

Comment: @200_success: Already done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long can code be?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/325/how-long-can-code-be)

Comment: @Vogel612: That (and most other related question I found) seem to be more about the maximum length the code should have.

Answer (score 3):

[Your question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113439/copyable-atomic) looks fine.  It has been upvoted and answered.